# How to change approval request post on record chatter feeds?

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed, approval-process

I have an Approval Process on Account. Every time I submitted for approval, there will be an approval post on Account's chatter feed like below.

**My question is, how to change the content of the post to display some fields of Account? or we cannot change it?**

[image]

I looked up in the document, and found there is a post template. I tried to change the post template but it seems the change works for the post on Approver's chatter feed, but not the post on record's chatter feed.

[image]

Comment: I tried to search that option but could not find for record chatter. The Post Template works for Chatter Feed on "Chatter Tab". If nothing works then you can think of using Feed Tracking for few fields which can appear on Record Chatter Feed.